# Let $\xi$ be an eigenvector of $A$. Let $\eta$ be such that $\{\eta, \xi \}$ is a base for $\Bbb R^2$, then...

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I came across the following bit on some notes I'm reading about ODEs, and couldn't figure out why this is true:

> Let $\xi$ be an eigenvector of $A$ with eigenvalue $\lambda$. Let $\eta$ be such that $\{\eta, \xi \}$ is a base for $\Bbb R^2$. Then $A\eta= c_1\eta +c_2 \xi $.
>
> Then:
>
> $$A_{\{\eta,\xi\}}=\begin{bmatrix}
>     c_1 & 0  \\
>     c_2 & \lambda 
>   \end{bmatrix}$$

Where $A_{\{\eta,\xi\}}$ denotes $A$ written in base $\{\eta, \xi\}$.

Why does $A$ look that why in that base?

Comment: Just compute $A(a,b)^T$ and see what it looks like.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the basis $\{\eta,\xi\}$, $\eta=\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}$ and $\xi=\begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}$. By multiplying the given matrix for $A$ with $\eta$ and $\xi$ you can see that it is the correct form.

Answer (score 2):

The recipe for writing a transformation $T$ as a matrix with respect to an ordered basis $\mathcal{B} = \{e_1, \ldots, e_n\}$ goes as follows: the entries of the $j$th column are the coefficients of $T e_j$, expressed as a linear combination of the $e_i$.